# Shopping cart adaptive card for Outlook

Tags: power-automate, powerapps, adaptive-cards, power-platform

I'm working with adaptive cards in power platform (especially with actionable messages for Outlook) and I'm wondering if it is possible to mimic a shopping cart in an actionable message (adaptive card version 1.4).

The user has a single dropdown list in which he select an item and a "+" button become visible at the right, he can click the "+" button to add the item to the shopping cart that is shown below the dropdown. The user should also be able to delete items from the shopping cart clicking an "X" button found at the right of every item in the cart. I did not find any way to do this at the moment
thanks

Comment: It is but actionable messages in Outlook won’t support it. Adaptive Cards in Teams will though. You can catch an action and then update an existing card.

Comment: Do you suggest using Cards for powerapp instead of simple Adaptive Cards?

Comment: A PowerApp is the logical approach but I was answering your question directly.